# Refer to a cshtml radio button

Tags: c#, razor

I have created the below radio button in cshtml but I cannot run the 'if' statement

```
<form method="post" id="Button">
     <input type="radio" name="HomeBtn" value="Assembly"
         id="AssemblyDrawings" checked/> Assembly Drawings
     <input type="radio" name="HomeBtn" value="Literature"
         id="RelatedLiterature"/>  Related Literature
</form>
```

The below C# is not working

```
@if(true) {
string things = String.Format("{0}", Request.Form["Button"]); 
  if (things == "Assembly") {
  {
     *do some stuff*
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be more specific about your problem. You say that you can't run the `if` statement. As I can assume the if statement is not in your view but in your controller. If that's true your syntax is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The purpose of the if statement is to determine which radio button is checked. Ideally I would like to keep it in my view and not involve the radio button with the controller. How would I accomplish this? Thanks